# Setting an image in the background of a JFrame in Java thanks to auto-generated code of Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, image

I want to set a image background on my JFrame thanks to automated generated code by Netbeans.

Unfortunately, I am facing this exact problem : 
http://www.areaofthoughts.com/2011/08/netbeans-jframe-properties-iconimage.html

When I tried to add it graphically, on details of iconImage, I have this error : "Custom editing of this property is not supported"

I tried the solution given in the link above, but unfortunately, this code doesn't work:

```
public ArrayList<Image> getIconImages() {
   ArrayList<Image> imageList = new ArrayList();
   imageList.add(getClass().getResource("/<resource_path>" +
     "/image.png")).getImage());
   return imageList;  
}
```

What is the problem in this code, and how can I fix this problem of background (by any way?).

Please note that when I did it for label with Netbeans, I had no problem for doing it. The generated code was, for example, the following:

```
jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/main/myimage/img.png")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally have two choices.

1- Create a custom `JPanel` that can paint the image as part of its background, then add this to your frame (once compiled, it can be dragged into the designer), have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

2- Set the layout of the `JFrame` to `BorderLayout`, add a JLabel to the frame.  Assign a image/icon to the label.  Set the layout of the label to what ever you need and your components toit.

You may need to adjust the horizontal & vertical position of the icon within the label to suit your needs

For an example, check out this previous answer [Place JLabel on top of JLabel with image in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253979/place-jlabel-on-top-of-jlabel-with-image-in/12254063#12254063)

Comment: I see. So new question, how to place some JLabel behind all components that already exists with "Design"(graphical way) part of netbeans?

Comment: The simplest way I can think off is to either set the frame's `contentPane` to the background component (you'll need to code this so it appears before the `initComponents` method) or simply drag you're resulting component into the designer and drop your components ontop of it...