# Null layout at Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, null-layout-manager

****SOLVED:****I made a Jframe with a specific background that I need. I found on Youtube that if I want to have a picture for background,you have to choose Null Layout.I did it,and when I run my program then the window remains small(not at normal size) at left corner on my screen. I need Null Layout because I use other labels up to Label,which I use as background.I have almost done with my project,and I have only this problem.Any idea?
Thank you!*
          ****I found the solution. You can choose Absolute Layout and it has no problem !!!**

Comment: Youtube is not the best place to learn this.

Comment: *"if I want to have a picture for background,you have to choose Null Layout"* - Not true...You can use a `JLabel` as the main background or use a `JPanel`, overriding it's `paintComponent` method to render the image. Both these allow you to supply a layout manager and be set as the frame's content pane...Oh, I assume you're using `pack` on the frame as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think this constructor, [`JLabel(Icon image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(javax.swing.Icon)) creates a label with only an image for you

Comment: @vandale That's my point. If you don't need to dynamically change the size of the image, you can simply use a `JLabel`.  A `JLabel` is just a `JComponent`, hence you can apply a layout manager to and add components to it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry, I misread,: I thought you meant to override the `paintComponent` on the `JLabel` also

Comment: @vandale No worries ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If i use a jlabel and then I add other components to it,then I can not see other components because they will be under the Jlabel,which I want for background.

Comment: @user2933161 If you add components to a container, they will be rendered above the container, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253979/place-jlabel-on-top-of-jlabel-with-image-in/12254063#12254063)

Comment: I found the solution. You can choose Absolute Layout and it has no problem !!!

Comment: If you have found the answer on your own, you should post an answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: @user2933161, `You can choose Absolute Layout and it has no problem` - That is NOT the solution. You should NOT use a null layout. All you need to do is use a layout manager like you would do for any other panel that you want to add components to.